# Does Asp.Net Core preserve CallContext across requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

Does Asp.Net Core preserve CallContext across requests?

We have a use case to attach contextual properties (username) to the thread, which can be pulled from our logging framework (NLog, [MDLC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer)). MDLC uses `CallContext` as far as I can tell.

We need each request to have clean contextual properties. Do we need to clear the CallContext at the beginning?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `TLS` in async scenarios. Use `CallContext` or `AsyncLocal<T>`.

Comment: When you say *across requests*, do you mean across sequential HTTP requests made to your API? If so, then you cannot guarantee they will run against the same thread anyway. This whole approach seems a little flawed.

Comment: @tukaef  we are using https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer . There isn't a huge amount of documentation on how it works, but it looks like it uses CallContext. I've reworded my question.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, but you certainly don't want to attach something like a username to a thread. In a multi-threaded environment like a web server, a particular user could be using any number of different threads, even during the same request. You're going to end up leaking across user requests.

Comment: @ChrisPratt To clarify, our use case is that we need to capture the username associated with the request (passed through HTTP headers) and log it in all downstream logs. As you said, this is an asynchronous environment and the request can switch threads. However I thought that LogicalCallContext should flow through async / await (if not Task.Run). In our logging output, we capture the username from the HTTP Header if `HTTPContex.Current` is available, and fallback to the LogicalCallContext which is populated in middleware. If this is not the correct approach, can you suggest a better one?

Comment: If the requirement is simply that you need to be able to put the username into logs wherever you're logging from, your best bet is creating a facade for your logger that has `IHttpContextAccessor` injected into its constructor. Then, you can access `HttpContext` directly to get the username and proxy that into your log.

Answer (score 1):

[NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/) provides lots of layout renderers that can capture HttpRequest-context-properties for logging (Without needing to inject into NLog MDLC).

This will probe the HttpRequest-Header for the value `JSNLog-RequestId`, and if empty fallback to the AspNetCore-RequestId, and if also empty then fallback to [AspNetCore-TraceIdentifer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.traceidentifier)

```
${aspnet-request:header=JSNLog-RequestId:whenEmpty=${mdlc:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-traceIdentifier}}}
```

List of available [${aspnet} Layout-renderers](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore)

NLog uses [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1) on NetCore, and if you are using Microsoft Extension Logging (MEL), then you can use [ILogger.BeginScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.beginscope) to inject properties into [NLog MDLC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging#beginscope) (And clear when leaving scope)

NLog MDLC can also be filled using [MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer#scoped-item) that also will clear when leaving using-scope.

Answer (score -1):

We use Serilog (should be more or less equivalent with NLog).  It has a very good integration with the ILogger from Aspnet core.

You can create a middleware and use the `ILogger.BeginScope`

```
public class LoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<LoggerMiddleware> _logger;

    public LoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<LoggerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Username", context.User?.Identity?.Name; }
        };

        using (_logger.BeginScope(dictionary))
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

With our Serilog integration, we are able to use `Username` in our log templates and it's preserved throughout the HTTP call (with different threads).

You NLog integeration should be similar following this wiki https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Comment: How does `BeginScope` work with existing `ILogger` instances in objects that are Singleton, Scoped or Transient?